# Replace certain img src with another via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I'm trying to replace all the `src` for all images on my page when the `src` is something specific:

```
$("img").each(function(i, elem){
    if ($(this).attr("src") == "/images/oldimage.png"){
        console.log("yay!") //this doesn't log anything
        $(this).attr("src", "/images/mynewimage.png");
    }
});
```

I figured the above would work, but it doesn't seem to be. It's not finding anything that matches my `if` statement, which I tested with the `console.log`, but there are lots of `img` that should match.

Comment: Have you tested what the value of `$(this).attr("src")` actually is (by logging it)?

Comment: @Quentin Good idea. Turns out it's not finding the images that I need in the  ``this``, but I'm targeting an ``img`` like this: ``<img class="cx-label-indicator indicator-right" height="14" width="14" src="/images/resources/indicators/hd/ind-triangle-down-red.png">`` Shouldn't that work?

Comment: The `src` value of the object will contain the full path, to get the actual `src` from the source, try `img.getAttribute('src')`

Comment: "Turns out it's not finding the images that I need" — What is it finding? Nothing?

Comment: @Quentin It is finding other images with ``img`` , but not the ones I need. Thinking they might be added to the page after my script.

Comment: This will be a lot easier to help you if you can put it into https://plnkr.co/ or  http://jsfiddle.net or http://codepen.io

Comment: Make sure your code is in `$(document).ready()`. But if they're added dynamically by other JS, you need to run your loop after that happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **getAttribute** and **setAttribute** to make this.

```
var aExample = document.querySelectorAll("img");
for(var i = 0; i < aExample.length; i += 1) {
    if(aExample[i].getAttribute("src") === "images/old.png") {
        aExample[i].setAttribute("src", "images/new.png");
    };
};
```